# Display an Image from imgur

Tags: android, imgur

I was able to upload a picture in Imgur and to get the link using example given in the API site. 
What I can't do is retrieve Bitmap or Drawable from URL.
And I find no documentation about it.

```
URL url= "http://imgur.com/1awAsRh"
Bitmap mPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

mPic is null.

I see that the image url on the site is https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDlBm.jpg
I see the picture can be png jpg etc...

Is there a way to get direct Image URL, is it always the same pattern?

Tx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, which implements an AsyncTask to do stuff in the background (needed for Android 4.0+):

```
class loadimage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(YourClass.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading.setMessage("Loading Image...");
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String stringurl = "http://imgur.com/1awAsRh"
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(stringurl).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        // do what you want with your bitmap
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this in your `onCreate`:

```
new loadimage().execute();
```

You also need to make sure you have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it is exactly as I did, but the line 
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(stringurl).getContent()); 
return null. It should be because the img is http://i.imgur.com/1awAsRh.jpg and not http://imgur.com/1awAsRh

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

From Imgur API page : https://api.imgur.com/models/image

instead of getting id param, I can use link param ( From JSON)